# How to connect java and javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, html, applet

I have tried connecting html and javascript using applet,but the try went in vain,so I have to know is there any other replacement than applet to connect html and javascript .

Comment: Did you go through this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingJavaScriptFromApplet.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It was valuable and helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jsp instead of applet. although jsp is vast in approach but still you can use it for basic java code easily.  simply wrap your java code in `<% java codes %>`  and place this over html code and to print variables use `<%=variableName%>` between html or javascript codes. you have to use .jsp extension to save file and tomcat/glassfish server to run.